# How to add the different views for different segments in the segment control?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i use the segment control with 5 segments.Every segment has separate view.So when we click on any segment another view will be appear below the segment control at the same view.Like this all segments print the different views in the same view.How to get this please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

IBOutlet UIView *view1,*view2,*view3,*view4,*view5; // don't forgot to connect in xib

-(IBAction)segValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender; //connect this method in xib with SegmentedControl

in .m file

-(IBAction)segValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender{

view1.hidden = TRUE;

view2.hidden = TRUE;

view3.hidden = TRUE;

view4.hidden = TRUE;

view5.hidden = TRUE;

switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) 
{

```
    case 0:
        view1.hidden = FALSE;
        break;
    case 1:
        view2.hidden = FALSE;
        break;
    case 2:
        view3.hidden = FALSE;
        break;
    case 3:
        view4.hidden = FALSE;
        break;
    case 4:
        view5.hidden = FALSE;
        break;
}
```

}